# Need to compare current time in bash shell linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am using below script  in bash to compare the current time and change the value of `$VAL`. But this script gives

> ./valscr.sh: line 14: syntax error: unexpected end of file

There is no line 14 in this script.

```
export NOW= `date +"%k%M"`
export VAL="O" 
if [ $NOW -lt 1200]; then
export VAL="M"
fi
if [ $NOW -ge 1200 -a $NOW -lt 1800 ]; then
export VAL="U"
fi
if [ $NOW -ge 1800 ]; then
export VAL="E"
fi
echo $NOW
echo $VAL
```

Comment: Note that `export NOW= \`date +"%k%M"\` ` should actually be `export NOW=\`date +"%k%M"\` ` (with no space after the `=`).

Comment: Apart from @ruakh's note: there should however be a space between `1200` and `]` in the 3rd line.

Comment: The script works with bash. Be more specific.

Comment: You don't need to export the variables unless they will be used by a child process. Please check your code with shellcheck.net

Comment: When you check against `-lt 1200` and `-ge 1800`, you know the rest will have `val="U"`. The variables in lowercase is a good habit, use the `else` in ìf-then-else-fi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I copied your script I get errors due to spaces in your variable assignment and 'test' conditions (no spaces after an '=' and space needed before ']').  When I resolved those items, then the script works.  Your error, however, suggests that you have 'hidden' characters in your file, i.e.  '\r' (return character.)

To check for this, try, 'cat -E your_file'.

See any '^M's or other strange characters?  Note that you should see '$' (end-of-line markers.) Remove the '^M's or other 'bad control codes' and you script should work...

:)
Dale